# Syncing Text using PUN in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, photon

I'm making a simple Word Builder type of game (where one player enters a word, and the other player enters a word starting with the last letter of the first player's word), and I can't get the Text to show up on both the screens.
I'm able to get the text to show up if I hard code it, like:

```
    [PunRPC]
    public void DisplayWord ()
    {
        MainWord.text = "Word";
    }
```

But I can't get it to display the word a player just entered to both screens, I thought this code would word:

```
    [PunRPC]
    public void DisplayWord ()
    {
        MainWord.text = UsedString;
        //UsedString is the word the (one of the) players just entered.
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much!

Here's the full code for entering a word:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class DictionaryScript : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    List<string> DictA = new List<string> () { 
    "a",
    "aa",
    "aaa",
    "aah",
    "aahed",
    "aahing",
    "aahs",
    "aal",
    "aalii",
    "aaliis",
    "aals",
    "aam",
    "aani",
    "aardvark",
    "aardvarks",
    "aardwolf",
    "aardwolves",
    "aargh",
    "aaron",
    "aaronic",
    "aaronical",
    "aaronite",
    "aaronitic",
    "aarrgh",
    "aarrghh",
    "aaru",
    "aas",
    "aasvogel",
    "aasvogels"};

    public List<string> DictAUsed = new List<string>() { };

    public string UsedString;
    public string NewString;

    public InputField inputField;
    public Text AddedWord;
    public Text MainWord;
    public Text TurnText;

    public Text ConnectedText;
    public Button StartButton;
    public Canvas OverlayCanvas;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void Awake()
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
        {
            StartButton.enabled = true;
            OverlayCanvas.enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            StartButton.enabled = false;
            OverlayCanvas.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.InRoom)
        {
            ConnectedText.text = "Connected!";
        }
    }

    public void StartGame ()
    {
        photonView.RPC("CanvasDisplay", RpcTarget.All);
    }

    public void MyWord (string newWord)
    {
        string newString = newWord.ToLower();
        print(newString);

        if (DictA.Contains(newString) && newString[0] == MainWord.text[0] && !DictAUsed.Contains(newString))
        {
            
            UsedString = newString;
            Debug.Log(UsedString);
            photonView.RPC("OnInput", RpcTarget.All);
        }

        else
        {
            print("This word does not exist!");
            AddedWord.text = newString + " is not a valid word!";
        }

        inputField.text = "";
    }


    [PunRPC]
    public void OnInput ()
    {
        DictAUsed.Add(UsedString);
        AddedWord.text = "The word was: " + UsedString;
        photonView.RPC("DisplayWord", RpcTarget.All);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void DisplayWord ()
    {
        MainWord.text = UsedString;
        //UsedString is the word the (one of the) players just entered.
    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void CanvasDisplay()
    {
        //string Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        string Alphabet = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        MainWord.text = Alphabet[Random.Range(0, 25)].ToString();
        StartButton.enabled = false;
        OverlayCanvas.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

I only have words starting with 'aa' for now, I'll add all the words once I can get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UsedString` is not synchronized in your network => Each player might have a different value for `UsedWorld` at the moment the RPC get called.

Why not pass on the `UsedWord` as argument to `OnInput` and `DisplayWord`?

Also why is `DisplayWord` even called via RPC at all? Since `OnInput` is alreay synchronized to `ALL` you could simply call the method right away

```
...
    photonView.RPC(nameof(OnInput), RpcTarget.All, UsedWord);
...

[PunRPC]
public void OnInput (string usedString)
{
    DictAUsed.Add(usedString);
    AddedWord.text = "The word was: " + usedString;

    // since this shall happen on any client as well
    // why even call it via RPC?
    // OnInput is called on ALL anyway so just do it right away
    DisplayWord(usedString);
}

public void DisplayWord (string usedString)
{
    MainWord.text = usedString;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This seemed to fix it. I had tried something similar, but I was not sure how to call an RPC method with arguments, this cleared it.